# How to insert new line on label when pressed enter in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I am dynamically changing the value of a text (destinationtext) using an input with javascript. It's a multiline input. But i can't add a new line at destination text when I press enter. How can i do this?

```
   <div id="canvas1">
            <img src="~/img/temp_promosyon+fiyat_mobil.jpg" class="background1" />
            <img class="picturecanvas1mob" id="pic1mob" src="~/img/karisik_sandvic-mobil.jpg">
            <div class="logocanvas1mob"><span></span></div>
            <div class="destinationtext"><span id="destinationtext">@Model.PromosyonMetin</span></div>
            <div class="promfiyat1mob"><span id="fiyatmobdest">@Model.Fiyat</span></div>
        </div>

.... inside the form this is the input i use 

<div class="form-group row">
                <label asp-for="PromosyonMetin" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Metin</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea asp-for="PromosyonMetin" type="text" class="form-control" id="sourceinput" placeholder="Bol kabaklı mücver menüsü..." onKeyPress="copyText()"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

....
```

This is the div's style

```
  .destinationtext {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 289px;
        width: 233px;
        height: 122px;
        line-height: 122px;
        z-index: 13;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Hind;
        font-size: 16px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: white;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

I'm using this simple code to change values

```
  $(function () {
        $('#sourceinput').keyup(function () {
            $('#destinationtext').text($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

My problem basically looks like this:

[image: my canvas and text input]

Comment: Two things in you textarea: 1) you have a wrong double quote on `type"="text"`, and 2) you have a `onKeyPress="copyText()"` and I don't know what that does or is supposed to do. Without those, [your script works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/b0yj61ko/).

Comment: Thanks, i deleted the wrong double quote in the type attribute but still not working. copyText() function is another function i use which is not related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see line breaks in your `span` element, you need to change the newline character from the input into a `<br>` tag. Something like:

```
$('#sourceinput').keyup(function () {
    $('#destinationtext').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
});
```

Note that I'm using `.html()` instead of `.text()` because `.text()` would encode HTML tags. The main difference is that `.html()` will replace any other HTML content that you might have in the span.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to apply a style to the `div`

```
#destinationtext {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank didn't work for me, unfortunately. Thanks for your help